# Беда... я не доганяю как посадить вёрстку на WP

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Не могу найти нормального туториала в котором рассказывается как посадить вёрстку на WP + чтобы это всё можно было с админки редактировать (текст менять, картинки и т.п.).

Допустим у меня есть LP. Я беру underscores и на его основе буду делать шаблон, но толковых уроков в рунете нет. Я понял что нужно секции нужно выводить в ребриках с помощью циклов.

Подкиньте туториалов. Как текстовых так и видео. В гугле меня не забанили, но самому трудновато искать в буржнете.

Я читал про кастомные поля(ACF). Я вообще в целом не доганяю что и куда. Инфы в сети нет вообще. Если отложить кастомные поля, то сначала нужно разобраться как с помощью рубрик в нужном порядке вывести секции LP + какие там циклы нужны чтобы можно было всё из админки выводить. Вокруг все говорят что WP такой лёгкий и удобный, а для меня это как ядерную бомбу собрать. Ничего не понимаю.

Подсобите =)

Comment: сам по этому каналу учился, очень все толково и наглядно рподемоснтрировано: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVQDbc6pkFg

Comment: Смотрите этот тутор: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqYhOkQfdeA Инфы в сети куча
https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-fields

Comment: Как это в сети нет инфы по wordpress? Инфы просто куча, но без минимального знания `php` будет трудновато. Вот на мой взгляд лучшие источники по WP: [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/) - нет ничего лучше официального источника. [wordpress.org](https://ru.wordpress.org/) - то же но на русском. [wp-kama](http://wp-kama.ru/) - достаточно полезный ресурс. Ну и немного видео уроков: [Wordpress - мастер](http://nnmclub.to/forum/viewtopic.php?t=763502). Достаточно что-бы понять и разобраться с устройством движка и сделать простенькую тему. [WordPress-профессионал](http://nnmclub.to/forum/viewtopi

Answer (score 3):

Для вывода записей из конкретной рубрики:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts ("category=9&orderby=date&numberposts=10"); ?>
    <?php if ($posts) : ?>
        <?php $i=0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata ($post); ?>
               тело html
            <?php $i++; if ($i==2) $i=0; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Для конкретной записи по id:

```
<?php $my_postid = 472;$content_post = get_post($my_postid); ?>
<?php $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    echo $content; ?>
```

Плюс используй плагин "Произвольные поля":
`<?php $field = get_field('slide2', 291); ?>` шорт-код ессессно

Плюс wp-kama.ru в помощь

Comment: И ты думаешь он поймет здесь чего? Для него это просто набор кракозябров

Comment: методом "тыка" можно попробовать, каму постараться по примерно освоить или же по логике ''category='' && "$my_postid=" посмотрев на числа подставить свой id записи и увидеть результат, а дальше больше